# How to get an ipywidget to wait for user input, then continue running your script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying to make my notebook more interactive. In particular, i want users to be able to run a function imported from a script which requires user input. At the moment, I'm just using python's input() function. However, this doesn't seem that user-friendly, as often the inputs I want in my script belong to one of several variables, or are a path to a file on the user's machine. I therefore looked into ipywidgets as it provides much nicer ways to input objects like this, without manually having to type a path, for example.

The issue is that I can't get the ipywidgets to pause the code and wait for user input. The rest of the script just continues instantly. I've tried a few different solutions. Notably, I've tried the first two methods described here: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html, alongside some similar custom solutions which ask the user to select a button once they're happy with their input. These methods work in that they wait for user input, but the main issue here is that I'm not sure how to get the code to continue in the script once the input has been selected. The only thing I can think of at the moment is to put the entire rest of my script into a new function that is called within the generator loop once it's received an input. However, my script is going to include lots of different user input widgets, and this method will get really messy really quickly. For example, i could nest two widgets like so:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

button = widgets.Button(description="Enter")
w = widgets.Select(
    options=['Linux', 'Windows', 'macOS'],
    value='macOS',
    description='OS:',
    disabled=False
)

button2 = widgets.Button(description="Enter")
w2 = widgets.Select(
    options=['A', 'B', 'C'],
    value='A',
    description='Letter:',
    disabled=False
)

output = widgets.Output()

display(w, button, w2, button2, output)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    with output:
        print(w.value)
        button2.on_click(second_click)
        
        
def second_click(b):
    with output:
        print(w2.value)
    
        
button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

Which sort of works, but you can see how this is going to get really messy really quickly.

So my question is, is there any way to get an ipywidget to behave like the python input() function: that is, wait for user input, then continue running the rest of the script?

Update: I solved it with the help of this package: https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-ui-poll/

This is a surprisingly tricky problem so many thanks to the authors.

Here's an example bit of code for others who run into this problem:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from jupyter_ui_poll import ui_events

# Create the widget
widget = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['a','b','c'],
    value=None,
    disabled=False)

# Create a function to continue the execution
button_clicked = False
def on_click(b):
    global button_clicked
    button_clicked = True

# Create a button widget
button = widgets.Button(description="Continue")
button.on_click(on_click)

# Display the widget and button
display(widget, button)

# Wait for user to press the button
with ui_events() as poll:
    while button_clicked is False:
        poll(10)          # React to UI events (upto 10 at a time)
        time.sleep(0.1)

# Get the selected value from the widget
selected_value = widget.value
print("Selected value:", selected_value)

# Rest of your code here
print("Continuing execution...")
# Add your code here to continue running the rest of the script based on the selected value
```

Comment: You can also check Mercury framework to create User Interface for your notebook. It is very simple framework https://github.com/mljar/mercury It has Stop function that can be called when waiting for user input https://runmercury.com/docs/output-widgets/stop/